# Tradingview Light Weight Chart: How to set the width of a candlestick body

Tags: javascript, lightweight-charts

I am practising Trading View's lightweight chart library by using [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/dkqr2w?file=/src/index.js) code. Everything works fine... all I want to set the width of the candle body, I want to decrease it. Is it possible? Right now the width decreases only if there are many candles.